# macro takes multiple pairs of arguments

Tags: customize, elisp-macros, defcustom, custom

I found this snippet of code from [oremacs](https://github.com/abo-abo/oremacs/blob/github/init.el#L38)

```
(defmacro csetq (variable value)
  `(funcall (or (get ',variable 'custom-set) 'set-default) ',variable ,value))
```

I would like to expand this macro so that is can take multiple pairs of arguments similar to `setq` (e.g. `(csetq foo 'bar fod 'baz str "a")` etc). I made an initial attempt, but it always returns `nil` and leaves me with a lot of nested `progn` forms when expanded.

```
(defmacro csetq (variable value &rest rest)
  (when variable
      `(progn (funcall (or (get ',variable 'custom-set) 'set-default) ',variable ,value)
              (csetq ,(car rest) ,(cadr rest) ,(cddr rest)))))
```

Is there a way to fix this macro so that it returns the last value set (similar to `setq`and does not nest?

Comment: It returns `nil` because this is the terminating condition for your recursion, i.e. `when` will evaluate to `nil` when you exhausted the list of `rest`. You can change the terminating condition to be a test for single last element instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options, but here's one approach:

```el
(defmacro csetq (&rest pairs)
  "For each SYMBOL VALUE pair, calls either `custom-set' or `set-default'."
  (let (forms)
    (while pairs
      (let ((variable (pop pairs))
            (value (pop pairs)))
        (push `(funcall (or (get ',variable 'custom-set) 'set-default)
                        ',variable ,value)
              forms)))
    `(progn ,@(nreverse forms))))
```

Comment: While for illustration purposes this is OK, in principle, this requires storing the value of evaluation of `,variable` and reusing it. It may be an expression, not necessarily a symbol, in which case you may get inconsistent results.

Comment: It's a good point, but I don't think it's an issue here in practice.  I believe the intention was that it would always be a symbol; and in any case `(get ',variable 'custom-set)` necessitates that the value of `variable` is a symbol, no?

Comment: yes @phils is right, just as `setq` auto-quotes the variable argument, this macro does the same.